# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing this code straight off a book but get this error. I have tried to assign variables to quicksort less, greater and[pivot] and then try to add it but it still doesn't work. here is the code and the error message is " TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'"

```
def quicksort(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return 
    else:
        pivot = array[0] #Recursive case
        less = [i for i in array[1:] if i <= pivot] 
        greater = [i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot] 
        return quicksort(less) + [pivot] + quicksort(greater)
print(quicksort([10, 5, 2, 3]))
```

Comment: Hint: what will this function return if `len(array) < 2`?

Comment: Using `return` without any value will return `None`. That is probably not what you want to do.

Comment: pivot , sort and greator are not a string, you can not use this format and + , you can use ( , ) instead + . return quicksort(less) , [pivot] , quicksort(greater)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def quicksort(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array
    else:
        pivot = array[0] #Recursive case
        less = [i for i in array[1:] if i <= pivot] 
        greater = [i for i in array[1:] if i > pivot] 
        return quicksort(less) + [pivot] + quicksort(greater)
print(quicksort([10, 5, 2, 3]))
```

You need to return array if len is less than two.